# JavaScript-DHTML: Object values access

Tags: javascript, dom, html, dhtml

I'm writing a little exercise where I move things from one "select" to another. Works great! I don't have multi-select yet, but I'll do that later. More importantly, I thought I would add counters so that values associated with the "options" could be added up. That function doesn't seem to be working. When I move things from one column to the other the labels meant for the summed values are filled with the text 0[object Object]. I'm sure this is on account of a pretty obvious mistake, but I lack the vocabulary to articulate the problem in any other terms. Please teach me? :-)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        #selectSource {
            width: 320px;
        }
        #selectTarget {
            width: 320px;
        }
        #wgtsum {
            width: 22px;
        }
        #cubesum {
            width: 22px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Loader</title>

<script>
    var data;
    var sumCube = 0;
    var sumWgt = 0;

    window.onload = function () {
        //Add way to load JSON data from a text file or something
        var load = document.getElementById('selectSource')
        data = [
        { num: "1", cube: 6, wgt: 2, title: "num: 1 cube: 6 wgt: 2" },
        { num: "2", cube: 4, wgt: 4, title: "num: 2 cube: 4 wgt: 4" },
        { num: "3", cube: 2, wgt: 6, title: "num: 3 cube: 2 wgt: 6" }
        ];

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            load.options.add(new Option(data[i].title, data[i].num));

        }

    }

    function sum() {
        var sumTarget = document.getElementById('selectTarget');

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (o = 0; o < sumTarget.length; o++) {
                if (sumTarget[o].value = data[i].value) {
                    sumCube = sumCube + data[i].cube;
                    sumWgt = sumWgt + data[i].wgt;
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("cubesum").setAttribute("value", sumCube);
        document.getElementById("wgtsum").setAttribute("value", sumWgt);
    }

    function move(from, to) {
        selected = from.options.selectedIndex;

        to.options.add(new Option(from.options[selected].text, from.options[selected].value));
        from.options.remove(selected);

        sum();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <select id="selectTarget" size="4">
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="move(this.form.selectSource, this.form.selectTarget)" style="width: 58px">To Target</button>


<button type="button" onclick="move(this.form.selectTarget, this.form.selectSource)" style="width: 58px">To Source</button>
<select id="selectSource" size="4">
</select>
<input value="0" type="text" id="cubesum" size="5"/>
<input value="0" type="text" id="wgtsum" size="5"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it perhaps that the format in which I've made the values doesn't store them as Integers? How could I fix this? What's the best Array/Object notation in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

In your "sum() " function it looks like your if statement should be doing a comparison == instead of an assignment =.

Comment: Hi, GMauro. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I've changed that but still receive the error. Any other thoughts?